# for_log generator returns no messages

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to get this for_log coroutine to work, what im trying to do is delete all messages from a specific month, in this case August, I went around the Internet and documentation, and also with the help from another question I posted here and came up with this:

```
@Client.command(pass_context = True)
async def clear(ctx, number: int, month, year):
    def around_month(month, year):
        begin = datetime.strptime(f'1 {month} {year}', '%d %b %Y')
        if begin.month == 12:
            end = datetime(begin.year+1, 1, 1)
        else:
            end = datetime(begin.year, begin.month, 1)
        return begin, end

    if ctx.message.author.id not in AdminIDs:
        await Client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'You do not have permission to use this command')
        return

    counter = 0
    begin, end = around_month(month, year)
    tmsg = await Client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Progress: 0/' + str(number))

    async for x in Client.logs_from(ctx.message.channel, limit = number, after=begin, before=end):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        await Client.edit_message(tmsg, 'Progress:' + counter + '/' + str(number))
        await Client.delete_messages(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
    await Client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'Operation completed! ' + 'Cleared: ' + str(counter) + ' items')
```

and then use `!fclear 100 AUG 2018`

This looks fine at first glance, but for some reason, it does not delete any messages, I inserted a counter to see if the for loop actually goes through the counter, and it gets nothing, it's still zero, interestingly enough, I tried to print the counter while it was inside the for loop, and it didn't print it to the console, the only reason I could think for that to happen is if it doesn't go to the for loop at all which may be because it doesn't find any messages? I'm not sure. There are no errors in the console or anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

> It gets nothing

This is a correct deduction. Working back from this, you'll find that `around_month` returns a tuple of the same date.

```
begin, end = around_month(month, year)
begin == end    # True
```

Taken from the Discord docs <sup>[1](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages)</sup>,

> The before, after, and around keys are mutually exclusive, only one may be passed at a time.

Given your need to delete messages from a specific month, you will need to fetch messages in that month until you exhaust the list of messages created in that month.

Also you need to invoke `Client.logs_from` with the snowflake time. There is a handy utility function for converting `datetime` object to a time snowflake. <sup>[2](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v0.16.12/discord/utils.py#L125)</sup>

```
from discord.utils import time_snowflake
from datetime import time delta

# ...
def before_time(messages, before):
    return [
        message for message in messages
        if message.id < before
    ]

after_dt = datetime.strptime(f'1 {month} {year}', '%d %b %Y')
before_dt = (after_dt + timedelta(days=31)).replace(day=1)
after = time_snowflake(after_dt)
before = time_snowflake(before_dt)

messages = await Client.logs_from(
    ctx.message.channel, limit=number, after=after
)
marked_for_deletion = before_time(messages, before)

while marked_for_deletion:
    await Client.delete_messages(marked_for_deletion)
    messages = await Client.logs_from(
        ctx.message.channel, limit=number, after=after
    )
    marked_for_deletion = before_time(messages, before)
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: What is `timedelta` ? It hasn't been defined according to Python, am I missing something?